# Is $CP$ instead of $C$ responsible for changing a particle to its antiparticle?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, neutrinos, antimatter, charge-conjugation

The charge conjugation operator $C$ reverses the charge of a state. But it may or may not convert a particle to its antiparticle. For example, consider a neutrino which is charge-neutral and left-handed while its antiparticle is also charge-neutral but right-handed. Therefore, charge conjugation is not sufficient to produce the antineutrino from a neutrino but CP is. $P$ is responsible for changing the chirality.

1. So is it not $CP$ instead of $C$ that is responsible for changing a particle to its antiparticle?
2. Is this fact related to the questions [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304038/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316990/)?

Answer (score 6):

### Answer to part 1

There is no natural pairing between particles and anti-particles at the level of individual states (any such pairing is purely a matter of convention), but there is a natural pairing between particle **species** — that is, between species and their anti-species. That's because Poincaré symmetries don't permute species, even though they do permute states. This statement also applies to discrete Poincaré transformations like a space-reflection transformation P, in theories where P is a symmetry.

Once we agree that the natural pairing is between **species**, not between individual states, the answer to part 1 of the question is easy:

- In a theory that has both CP and C symmetry, they both permute species the same way. It's not either-or, it's both. That's because in a theory with both CP and C symmetry, P is also a symmetry, so particles related by P are the same species, by definition.
- To accommodate theories that don't have C (or P) symmetry, we can use CP to define the paring between species and their anti-species. This works whether or not the theory has C symmetry, and when it does, C symmetry gives the same pairing.

Even more generally, we could use CPT (instead of CP) to define the pairing between species and their anti-species, as Weinberg does in chapters 2 and 3 of *Quantum Theory of Fields*, volume 1. This provides some context for part 2 of the question...

### Answer to part 2

Part 2 of the question asks whether part 1 is related to a couple of other questions about Sakharov's criteria for baryogenesis. Those criteria assert that to explain baryogenesis, the theory should not have either C or CP symmetry. The answer to

[Why are both C and CP violation necessary for baryogenesis?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304038/206691)

explains why this is so. It is also nicely explained in the comments following knzhou's answer to

[What distinguishes the behaviour of particle from its antiparticle: C violation or CP violation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410881/206691)

To relate this to part 1 of the present question, note that Sakharov's criteria can be restated without referring specifically to CP or C, like this: To explain baryogenesis, the theory should not have any symmetries between particle species and their anti-species among all symmetries that preserve the time-orientation (which excludes CPT).

Comment: You said the $C$ transformation is not unique. Any $C\Lambda$ is also a valid charge conjugation operation. I believe this is because $\Lambda$ cannot change an electron to something else which is not an electron! I get your point that choosing $C$ to the charge conjugation rather than $C\Lambda$ is just a convention. It will take me some time to go through the full answer. @DanYand

Comment: You need CP transformation to convert a left-handed neutrino to a right-handed antineutrino in the Standard Model. SM does not have a left-handed antineutrino.  Your answer suggests that the SM is CP-conserving which is not! What am I missing?

Comment: @SRS I replaced the answer. (The original answer didn't mean to suggest that the SM is CP-conserving, but it was a rambling and poorly-conceived answer. That's why I replaced it.)